# CSS - does the size of the css influence the page rendering

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if a stylesheet of 4000 lines can make a page rendering significantly slower in comparison to a stylesheet of 1500 lines. Of course both will be minified in the end. I was just having a look at sass exports that can become very big, especially if the "extend" functionality is used.

Comment: significantly? probably not

Comment: This will probably depend on the browser.

Comment: @Oriol so which browser is slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how the assets are loaded on the page - if they are render blocking or not.

So for example, assets loaded in the `<head>` of your page are render blocking. Therefore the bigger these assets, the more data the browser has to fetch before it starts to display markup/styling/etc.

Here is an article describing it: http://www.sitespeed.io/rules/

Therefore, I try to optimize my sites by only loading critical assets in the `<head>` of the document (core CSS, JS), and load secondary assets below or along side body content. Examples: (images are loaded inline obviously, and JS libraries used after page render are included right before the closing `</body>` tag).

Short answer, for any traditionally loaded assets in the `<head>` of a webpage - the larger they are in size, the "slower" a website will feel being loaded (all else held constant).

Answer (score 0):

It may cause an effect, but not it shouldn't make a big difference. There are two reasons for:

1. You need to download a large file.
2. The webbrowser needs to go through each line of code.